# How to write different RewriteRule to one rule in .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to Mod Rewrite, i just learnt a little bit so i tried to write different rules for each get parameter. Here is my full URL:

`localhost/index.php?view=some-page&city=some-city&ward=some-ward&price=some-price&page=some-page`

As you can see, there are 5 get parameters and the last four (city, ward, price, page) are optional. So i write different rules for each optional parameter like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# No 4 optional parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/?$    index.php?view=$1 [QSA,NC,L] 
# for set city parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$    /index.php?view=$1&city=$2 [NC,L] 
# for set price parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/price/([0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?view=$1&price=$2 [NC,L] 
#for set page parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)\.html$  /index.php?view=$1&page=$2 [NC,L] 
# for set city and page parameter
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/city/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?view=$1&city=$2&page=$3 [NC,L] 
# for set city, ward and page
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/city/([^/]*)/ward/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)\.html$    /index.php?view=$1&city=$2&ward=$3&page=$4 [NC,L] 
# all city, ward, price and page are set.
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/city/([^/]*)/ward/([^/]*)/price/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)\.html$  /index.php?view=$1&city=$2&ward=$3&price=$4&page=$5 [NC,L]
```

This is such a headache by looking at this and i don't know whether what i did is effecient or not. So What i ask here is that: instead of writting different rule for each case, can we just write one line of Rewriterule for all like this:

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]*)/city/([^/]*)/ward/([^/]*)/price/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)\.html$  /index.php?view=$1&city=$2&ward=$3&price=$4&page=$5 [NC,L]
```

And telling that rule if parameter city is not set (empty), then the mapping url should be without city like this:

```
/index.php?view=$1&&ward=$2&price=$3&page=$4
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If rewriting gets too complicated, then do it in your php based routing logic. More flexible, easier to understand.

Comment: Can you write what are pretty URLs you want to support?

Comment: what did you mean? But watever it is, please tell me if i can combine those rules into one with some condition to fit my case?

Comment: What are the URLs you're trying to rewrite with these rules?

Comment: for example: i want my url like this: $page/city/$city/ or $page/city/$city/ward/$ward...Currently have to write 2 different rules for parameter city and ward. So i would like to know despite what parameter is set, it still map to this single rule: `/index.php?view=$1&city=$2&ward=$3&price=$4&page=$5 [NC,L]`